# Highlighted active tab does not switch when clicked. Using Angularjs ui-router ui-bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angularjs ui-router ui-bootstrap tabs.
It works on http://plnkr.co/edit/EYLsPRlxEXQP4HsXuPKK?p=info but does not work on my website. The active tabs does not get highlighted when clicked. The correct content loads though.

```
var app = angular.module('Plunker', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

      .state('tab1', {
            url: '/tabpage1',
            templateUrl: 'tab1.html',
            controller:'tabsController' 
      })
      .state('tab2', {
            url: '/tabpage2',
            templateUrl: 'tab2.html',
            controller:'tabsController' 
      })

      .state('tab3', {
            url: '/tabpage3',
            templateUrl: 'tab3.html',
            controller:'tabsController' 
      })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

app.controller('tabsController',['$scope','$state',function($scope, $state){
    $scope.tabs = [
    { title: 'Announcements', route:'tab1', active:false},
    { title: 'Course Info', route:'tab2', active:true},
    { title: "Timetable", route: "tab3", active: false },
];


}]);
```

Can anybody kindly advise?
Thank you.

Comment: What does your code look like for your website?

Comment: i did exactly the same like in the plunker except the path to tab1/tab2/tab3.html points to one of the files in the yii2 folder. Could not understand why only the 'Course Info' tab gets highlighted as default but unable to change when clicked on. Are my codes correct? newbie in angularjs here.

Comment: DId you change the states and templates?

Comment: nope..i followed the same as plunker as i am setting up as an example to test first.

Comment: the tab change active highlight when i change the route: 'tab1' to route:'.tab1' and same for the other two tabs. Also for ".state('tab1', { ..." to ".state('.tab1', { ..." but doing so the content will not load.